# Node SQL Server IN query not working with request params

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I want to run a query in Node SQL Server which is using IN clause. This is the string used for querying `'a','b','c'`. This code works fine, but user is passing data so, I can't use it. May lead to attacks:

```js
const dbResult = await request.query(`
    SELECT OrderID, ParentSKURefNum, SKURefNum, OrderCompleteTime
    FROM ${tables.ORDERS}
    WHERE OrderID IN (${idsWithQuotes})
`);
```

I want to use `request.input('OrderIDs', ids)` and then code will be like this:

```js
request.input('OrderIDs', ids);
const dbResult = await request.query(`
    SELECT OrderID, ParentSKURefNum, SKURefNum, OrderCompleteTime
    FROM ${tables.ORDERS}
    WHERE OrderID IN (@OrderIDs)
`);
```

But the code above always shows: No data found. What am I doing wrong? In second situation I also tried removing first and last quote from the string assuming **request** automatically adds it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Replace `IN (@OrderIDs)` with `IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@OrderIDs, ','))`

Comment: @DanGuzman it's throwing error. ```Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'``` It's related to compatibility level. I don't know if I can change the compatibility of production database.

Comment: If you can't change the database compatibility level to 130 or higher (SQL 2016+), you'll need to create your own split function (you can find many with an internet search) or use a table-valued parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server 2012 which doesn't support STRING_SPLIT function to split CSV into some sort of table which then IN operator operates on.

I found it on stack overflow that we can split the values using XML which I didn't really understand but did the trick.

```js
    SELECT OrderID, ParentSKURefNum, SKURefNum, OrderCompleteTime
    FROM ${tables.ORDERS}
    WHERE OrderID IN (
      SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
      FROM
      (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@OrderIDs, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS xml) AS STRING
      ) AS A
      CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
    )
```